# Manipulating DOCX files using java.nio.FileSystems

Tags: java, xml, openxml, nio, docx

I'm manipulating MS word DOCX files using java.nio.FileSystems, but it is available with java 7 only but the problem is our server environment don't have a support for java 7. I really might need some aspects of java.nio.* in order to manipulate word document (editing the styles.xml using dom parsers APIs). Is there any other public, open-source APIs out there in order to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Apache Poi](http://poi.apache.org/) or [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) which can create and manipulate MS Office documents, including OOXML (like DOCX).

Comment: MystyxMac, I need to add, replace the entire word/theme folder, replace styles.xml with the newly created byte array representation and few parts of media. This is very handy when I create FileSystem for the zip (docx) file using java.nio package. I've gone through the Apache Poi quickly, org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem package, could solve the problems. Trying it. Thanks.

Comment: Also, seeing how far we can go through java.util.zip utility.